# Multiple Controllers with one Name in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, controllers

I receive the following error when trying to run my ASP.NET MVC application:

> The request for 'Account' has found the following matching controllers:
>   `uqs.Controllers.Admin.AccountController`
>   `MvcApplication1.Controllers.AccountController`

I searched the project for `MvcApplication1.Controllers.AccountController` to remove it, but I can't find a match.

I try to registered a route to fix it:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "LogAccount", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" },
     new string[] { "uqs.Controllers.Admin" } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

but that didn't solve it.

> Multiple types were found that match
>   the controller named 'Account'.

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have more than one controller named `Account` in your application, even in different namespaces.

You have to have these controllers split up by `Area` (a feature in ASP.NET MVC 2).

If you conduct a Find for `AccountController` you'll find all controllers named `Account` in your application; and move them off into different `Areas` if you want both of them, or delete one.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have two controllers in different namespaces, one inheriting from the other, and I do not use Areas.  Setting the namespace in the MapRoute (just like lovjii does above) fixed the same exact error message.  Is the difference that my controllers inherit from each other?

Answer (score 61):

If you refactor your project and change the default Namespace and Assembly from "MVCApplication1" to "uqs", you may end up with 2 assemblies in your bin directory (the new one and the old one). You can get this error because the AccountController is in both assemblies.

Clean your bin directory of the old MVCApplication1.dll.

Comment: cheers man, I've had this problem before and ended up creating a new project as I couldn't figure out what the problem was - I was stupidly thinking that a clean would clear the bin folder, not so if I've changed the assembly name eh??!!

Comment: I renamed my project and had the old dll file still in my bin folder -- this fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You sir are a Champion, thank you kindly! ASP.NET MVC seems to be relatively unfriendly when it comes to refactoring namespaces, this is yet another pitfall that "clean" doesn't even solve!

Answer (score 4):

Had this same problem.  Cleaned the bin and I was good to go.

Comment: Wasn't enough to clean the solution, I needed to removed old .dll files from bin as well

Answer (score 3):

A slightly confusing variation on the problem (similar in that it causes the same error message) can occur even with namespaces supplied. MVC 3 I think is a little pickier than MVC 2 on this front.

---

**Short Answer:**

Make sure the namespace of your controller is in fact the namespace specified in the `MapRoute` call!!

---

**Long Answer**:

I have 3 areas : `default ("")` / `Facebook` / `Store` and they each have `AdminController`

I have the route mapped like this (for my default area):

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Gateway", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new string[] { "RR.Controllers.Main" }
);
```

A request to /admin gave the following error :

> Multiple types were found that match
>   the controller named 'admin'. This can
>   happen if the route that services this
>   request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}')
>   does not specify namespaces...
>
> The request for 'admin' has found the
>   following matching controllers:
>
> RR.FacebookControllers.AdminController
>   RR.Controllers.AdminController 
>   RR.StoreControllers.AdminController

But wait a minute! Didn't I specify the controller namespace.... ? What's going on.... ?

Well it turned out my default area's admin controller namespace was `RR_MVC.Controller` instead of `Rolling_Razor_MVC.Controller.Main`.

For some reason in MVC 2 this didn't give a problem, but in MVC 3 it does. I think MVC 3 just requires you to be more explicit when there's potential ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

`AccountController` is automatically generated by the ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio template. It is located in `Controllers\AccountController.cs`. Try searching for it in the project and delete it.

Comment: sorry, may be i can't explain my problem. but, I know where located AccountController. but I haven't namespace with name MvcApplication1.Controllers.AccountController, i rename it to uqs.Controllers.Admin. and, trying to run my web app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem...

Solved by removing a project reference in one of the .csproj files