# MVC 3 finds same controller twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an application in C# using MVC 3 that has areas in it, and when I attempt to debug, I get the following error:

> ```
> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Access'.
> ```
>
> This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> ```
> The request for 'Access' has found the following matching controllers:
> ```
>
> FARM.Shared.Controllers.AccessController
>   FARM.Shared.Controllers.AccessController

There is only one controller with that name, so why is it listing the same controller twice, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you have another library that has a type with the same name? Or maybe you have a stale version of the web app binary loaded along with a new version, thus resulting in a conflict?

Comment: @marcind might be right, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627699/multiple-controllers-with-one-name-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: My coworker found the answer, and it just happens to be what @marcind suggested. I had an old dll in my bin directory and it was finding that namespace in there. So I deleted it and now it works. Thanks for the answers.